# SMS data field character

Tags: unicode, sms

I m looking up the format of GSM SMS.

When PDU mode is used, the TP-UD field is said to be one of the three, 7bit is for ascii symbol, 8 bit is for data, and UCS2 is for the unicode, like Japanese.

There is an example, `Hello!` has the TP-UD field `C8 32 9B FD 0E 01`. why? It's not ascii, not GSM03.38 basic character set.

And what if the user data is a mix of ascii character and Japanese, is it unicode for all?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Short message content encoding type(7-bit, 8-bit, 16 bit etc. ) is being chosen by looking the data coding scheme parameter value. If message content consists mixed characters of GSM default alphabet and unicode(e.g. Russian, Arabic, Japan etc), data coding scheme value must be set to 16 bit(UCS-2). 
GSM 7-bit default alphabet is for English and several European languages. A limited number of languages, like Portuguese, Spanish, Turkish may use 7-bit encoding with national language shift table defined in 3GPP 23.038. 8-bit encoding is dedicated to binary short messages.

Try Cloudhopper Java SMPP API Charset utility class

```
msgChars = CharsetUtil.encode("öàß", CharsetUtil.CHARSET_GSM);
msgChars = CharsetUtil.encode("Точно так и было!", CharsetUtil.CHARSET_UCS_2);
```